# Is it secure to have website files in public_html

Tags: reactjs, laravel, directory, next.js, public

I had a backend in Laravel and a frontend in react. Now a guy has converted my frontend to next.js.

My question, I see he had put my frontend in the public folder and backend in the public folder too, Before he converts I had a folder name website app outside the public folder.

But is it secure to have both backend and frontend in the public folder? Can someone download the whole website files when I have everything in the public folder?

It sounds a little weird to me.

Comment: You've tagged this Laravel so I'm assuming you mean there are your .php source files under /public, which is a red flag something is going wrong here.

Comment: yes, everything is in public_html folder. Looks so weird why he put everything there

Comment: No that's wrong. It is also a security concern because unless the webserver is very carefully configured you will end up exposing certain source files to the world

Comment: ohh sounds not great

Comment: @michelezsoltzsolten if you think the answer below is right please mark it as the solution, if not, add your own answer to this matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the whole project shouldn't be in the public folder, as its name says, it is for things that should have public access, and the other non-public files should be in folders above the public folder. This is a good practice, but put in mind that there is no best place to store your files safely. The safety of your sensible files is only a result of a combination of good security measures adopted in the server.

If your project is made with Laravel you should already have a public folder inside it, THAT is what should be inside the public folder on the server. Laravel treats the public folder as the content that is already compiled and "ready to show it" to the browser. Your views, css and js files are in the folder *resources*, and if you check your *public* folder it will have a css folder, a js folder and index.php. This is because Laravel allows the user to use Blade and Sass for example, and these things need to be processed and converted into the files you see in the *public* folder so the browser can understand them.

So you should use the *public* folder that Laravel gives you and not post the whole project in the public folder.

Comment: ok, Thank you. 

Is it ok to have next.js (frontend) in public folder and laravel backend outside the public folder? 

He have backend and frontend separate right now.

Comment: @michelezsoltzsolten yeah, I think that would be alright. Is it like frontend + API?

Comment: He have this now https://ibb.co/X5dB3Ph 

I dont if the know what he doing, I just want to be sure my website is secure.

When i ask him why he put everything in public he just "why not?"

Comment: He have 2 account in the server https://ibb.co/tB2NQNM 

One with backend and one frontend next.js,  Now he just have frontend source files in public. I don't know if it should be there. Looks weird.